# Python dir(function) vs dir('function')

Tags: python

I've been reading about dir function and here's the explanation from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_dir.asp).

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The `dir()` function returns all properties and methods of the specified
>   object, without the values.
>
> This function will return all the properties and methods, even
>   built-in properties which are default for all object.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `dir(object)`
>
> where object is The object
>   you want to see the valid attributes of

Then I tried it with different value such as `dir(print)` vs `dir('print')` and observed that they're producing different kind of output.

**dir(print)**

```
>>> dir(print)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__']
>>>
```

**dir('print')**

```
>>> dir('print')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
>>>
```

My question is what is the difference between these 2? `dir()` vs `dir('function')` or `dir(print)` vs `dir('print')` in this example.

Comment: `dir('print')` is showing you *the string `'print'`*'s items; which has nothing to do with the function `print`.

Comment: BTW, w3schools is... not a well-reputed source of material (despite the name, they have no association whatsoever with the W3C or any other official body; and their documentation is often out-of-date or incomplete). I'd strongly suggest using http://docs.python.org/ instead in the Python case, and with other languages, reviewing the SO tag wiki to find resources recommended by experts in that language.

Comment: Note that it says ***object***, not "name of function".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dir('print')
```

You're passing a string to `dir()`, so it's giving you all the properties and methods of the `str` class.
As BlueRine said:

> `dir('dasdasd') == dir('print')` will always return `True`

Comment: Ah, thanks @Jammy. I just notice it. `dir('print')` is producing similar output as `dir('test')` as they're actually a string

Comment: You may add that the result of a random string argument is the same for analogy. E.g. `dir('dasdasd') == dir('print')` gives `True`